# DNA Sequence Python not printing

Tags: python, dna-sequence

```
import random


def pair():
    base = random.choice('AGCT')
    if base == 'A':
        base = base + 'G'
    elif base == 'G':
        base = 'A' + base
    elif base == 'C':
        base = base + 'T'
    else:
        base = 'C' + base
    return base


def sequence():
    pair()
    n = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(base * n)


def main():
    pair()
    sequence()
    pair()
    sequence()
    pair()
    sequence()


main()
```

I have to create three sequences in the main function, concatenate them to form a larger sequence, and print the result.

> **But I keep getting an error, why?**
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File "/Users/nicole/Desktop/CS/dna.py", line 33, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "/Users/nicole/Desktop/CS/dna.py", line 27, in main
>     sequence()
>   File "/Users/nicole/Desktop/CS/dna.py", line 23, in sequence
>     print(base * n)
> NameError: name 'base' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Can you update your post with the error you're getting?

Comment: You need to return base, setting it as a variable only sets it in the scope of pair

Comment: Read about [4.2. Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#index-3)

Comment: @Nicole Please do not fix the code your provided, except for formatting, otherwise any answer we give does not make sense. Also, please provide the output you expect as there are clearly better way to do that. Why are you using random?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: The `random` part generates random `base` pairs e.g **AG, GA, CT ...**. The second "should" generate random length base strings.

Comment: @Nicole Please provide expected output

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to `base`. In your case it would look something like that:

```
def sequence():
    base = pair()
    n = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(base * n)
```

And you should try to avoid using a variable name multiple times, so you can read your code more easily. :)